# django generic view pagination by item id (not page number)

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-pagination

I love the ease of django's pagination system, but is there anyway to tweak it where it's paginating by item id instead of page number? Because I am ordering in descending order, if there is an update on a page while a user is going through the pages, the ordering is off.

For instance, if each page had 3 items

1. Item #1
2. Item #2
3. Item #3

While reading page 1, another user updates, then page 2 for the current user will be

1. Item #3
2. Item #4
3. Item #5

Comment: If you're storing the date when new items are added you could also additonally filter for the date, so newer items would be excluded!

Comment: the thing is, I'm using generic views.  So I don't think you can have the additional filter. Unless are you talking about making a query first, determining the date of the last post on the page, then using that date to set the query for generic views?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

To do this you'll need to write your own pagination system; Django's is designed to work with any list-like set of data and the page number system is intractably built in.